# how to touch event to get x and y co-ordinates in CustomImageRenderer in ios xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, uiimageview, touch-event

is it possible to get the x and y coordinates of a touch? If so could someone please provide a very simple example where the coordinates ios xamarin.

Android working fine

```
public CustomImageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Image> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            SetOnTouchListener(this);
        }

        public bool OnTouch(Android.Views.View v, MotionEvent e)
        {
            float Xaxis = e.GetX();
            float Yaxis = e.GetY();
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/touch/ios-touch-walkthrough

Comment: @Jason any other samples workaround, because i already check that link lot of errors getting

Comment: if you are getting errors and want help fixing them, then post the relevant code and the specific errors